# Using Low Variables and Grid to return a count

Tags: grid, low-variables

I'm building a slideshow using Grid and Low Variables. I have a checkbox to publish or hide the slide. What I can't figure out is how to get a count on the amount of items that are checked.

Using this:

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_homeslider" sort="random"}
    {lv_homeslider:checked}
{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

total_rows returns 5, but I only have 2 checked. Any ideas how to get the number for rows where checked=true?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Search parameter to return only rows that have the checkbox cell checked.

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_homeslider" search:name_of_checkbox_cell="true"}  
    {total_rows}
{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

"true" should be the actual value that you entered under "Multi-Select Options" in the checkbox field/cell settings.

Comment: Indeed, this would be the way to go.